# RxDart: Validating TextField double values

Tags: flutter, rxdart

I have a button enables GPS. When GPS is enabled a `TextField` should populate with the latitude values. When disabled the user should be able to enter in a latitude value. I need the user supplied value to be validated (in the range of -90.0 to 90.0).

Something like:

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: bloc.latitude,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Latitude',
                        labelText: 'Latitude',
                        errorText: snapshot.error),
                    onChanged: bloc.onLatitudeChanged,
                    //enabled: snapshot.hasData,
                    controller: _latitudeTextController,
                  );
                },
              ),
```

My bloc has:

```
final _latitudeController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
Function(String) get onLatitudeChanged => _latitudeController.sink.add;
Stream<String> get latitude => _latitudeController
                              .distinct()
                              .map((l) => double.parse(l))
                              .transform(validateLatitude) // double -> double
                              .map((l) => l.toString());
```

I have a number of issues. If the `map` fails I get a `FormatException` and I can't figure out how to handle that. My bloc also has a  `Stream<double> currentLatitude` when the GPS is enabled (else it spits out `Observable.empty()`) and I can't quite figure out how to work that in (probably a merge?. I think when the GPS is enabled I should just be able to set the text in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use `snapshot.hasData()` or `snapshot.hasError()` to check for data in snapshot, when using Stream Builder. This will at least solve the Observable.empty() issue. For the FormatException, you need to validate this in your validate function. Hope this helps!

May be something like this

```
 final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      _controller.text = snapshot.data;
    }
```

**Note:** Assign this _controller to controller in TextField.

Comment: That doesn't quite get me where I need to be since I also need to enable/disable the input when we're getting info from the GPS. I think I almost need to have a stream of `TextInputState` or something that contains the text, possible error and whether it's enabled or not.

Comment: when you get it from GPS,  set the TextInputState to disabled. This is a part of your architecture design.